Return the corresponding value Y for the nth instance of the occurence of value X in Excel
I have been using this formula for several years to return the corresponding value Y for the nth instance of the occurance of value X in numerous spreadsheets and it works perfectly every time:  (in this example, it is the 4th occurene of the value in cell D1237)
=INDEX(TCIREV24!$O$2:$O$3039,SMALL(IF($D1237=TCIREV24!$K$2:$K$3039,ROW(TCIREV24!$K$2:$K$3039)-ROW(INDEX(TCIREV24!K$2:$K$3039,1,1))+1),4))
I have been trying to replicate this same basic formula for a different project and have constructed this formula"
=INDEX(DIGIDOC_AMM_TOC!$I$2:$I$25634,SMALL(IF(B3=DIGIDOC_AMM_TOC!$C$2:$C$25634,ROW(DIGIDOC_AMM_TOC!$C$2:$C$25634)-ROW(INDEX(DIGIDOC_AMM_TOC!$C$2:$C$25634,1,1))+1),4))
but all I get for a return is #N/A.
I have tried every trick I know to check and recheck formats, columns, ranges, moving all the data to a fresh workbook, but nothing seems to work.  What am I missing?

Does Column C contain the error value #N/A in one or more cells?
